# AngularJS - request Não passa parametro

Tags: php, angularjs

Meu código é esse, porem no código php não recebo o parametro ref... O que pode ser ?

```html
$http({
         method: 'POST',
         url:  '../assets/php/client/PHP.php',
         data: {ref: 'dataTableLoad'}
         }).then(function (response) {// on success
         //alert(response.data);
         console.log(response.data);
         $('#dataTableTboody').html(response.data);},
         function (response) {
         console.log(response.data,response.status);
         });
```

O meu php ecebe da seguinte forma :

```html
if (isset($_POST['ref']) && $_POST['ref'] != '') {
    init($_POST['ref']);
} else {
    $data['response'] = -1;
    echo json_encode($data);
    exit;
}
```

Ele só me retorna -1
Obrigado

Comment: Faça um teste vendo se não está vindo no stream de input com `file_get_contents('php://input')` , se estiver é só usar o json_decode para retornar o input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verifique se no $POST vem o objeto data, se eu não estiver muito enferrujado em PHP esse código abaixo deve funcionar caso o objeto venha como data

```
if (isset($_POST['data']->ref) && $_POST['data']->ref != '') {
    init($_POST['data']->ref);
} else {
    $data['response'] = -1;
    echo json_encode($data);
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Você está passando a string literal `'dataTableLoad'` para o servidor.

Imagino que você queira passar o *valor* de `dataTableLoad`. Tente assim:

```
$http({
     method: 'POST',
     url:  '../assets/php/client/PHP.php',
     data: {ref: dataTableLoad} // Perceba que retirei as aspas simples.
```

Comment: deu outro erro : ReferenceError: dataTableLoad is not defined

Comment: na realidade preciso passar o valor literal da string... esse é o valor que preciso passar

Comment: @AugustoFurlan então você está tentando passar uma variável que nunca foi definida.

Comment: @OneSendai na realidade, não é variavel, mas sim string direto ....